# How can terms in a JSON-LD context compact OWL NamedIndividuals to JavaScript objects?

Tags: protege, json-ld

An expanded JSON-LD file was saved from Protege and I would like to write a context that compacts the JSON-LD such that the NamedIndividuals become Javascript objects.  My JSON-LD file provides orbital parameters for planets.

I attempted to define "earth" as a term but it did not have the desired effect of replacing the @id and @type.  What I'd like is a compact JSON-LD file that I can parse into an object and access parameter values with something similar to `mars.inclination`, or `graph[i].inclination`.  Guidance and examples would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is a portion yet complete JSON-LD file with the context I developed in JSON-LD Playground:

```
   {
  "@context": {
    "demo": "http://example.org/demo#",
    "decimal": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal",
    "owl": "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#",
    "label": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label",
    "comment": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment",
    "eccentricity": {
      "@id": "demo:eccentricity",
      "@type": "decimal"
    },
    "inclination": {
      "@id": "demo:inclination",
      "@type": "decimal"
    },
    "omega": {
      "@id": "demo:omega",
      "@type": "decimal"
    },
    "sma": {
      "@id": "demo:sma",
      "@type": "decimal"
    },
    "raan": {
      "@id": "demo:raan",
      "@type": "decimal"
    },
    "tau": {
      "@id": "demo:tau",
      "@type": "decimal"
    },
    "period": {
      "@id": "demo:period",
      "@type": "decimal"
    },
    "earth": {
      "@id": "demo:Earth",
      "@type": "owl:namedIndividual"
    }
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "demo:Earth",
      "@type": [
        "owl:NamedIndividual",
        "demo:Orbit"
      ],
      "eccentricity": "0.016708",
      "inclination": "7.155",
      "omega": "-11.26064",
      "period": "365.256363",
      "raan": "23.4392811",
      "sma": "1",
      "tau": "114.20783",
      "label": "Earth"
    },
    {
      "@id": "demo:Mars",
      "@type": [
        "owl:NamedIndividual",
        "demo:Orbit"
      ],
      "eccentricity": "0.0934",
      "inclination": "5.65",
      "omega": "49.558",
      "period": "686.971",
      "raan": "317.68143",
      "sma": "1.523679",
      "tau": "286.502",
      "label": "Mars"
    },
    {
      "@id": "demo:Mercury",
      "@type": [
        "owl:NamedIndividual",
        "demo:Orbit"
      ],
      "eccentricity": "0.20563",
      "inclination": "3.38",
      "omega": "48.331",
      "period": "88",
      "raan": "281.01",
      "sma": "0.387098",
      "tau": "29.124",
      "label": "Mercury"
    },
    {
      "@id": "demo:Orbit",
      "@type": "owl:Class"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: JSON-LD "is based on JSON" and "is developer friendly", yeah? I'm afraid this is impossible even with all those contexts, flattenings, compactions and framings... Find a library to work with JSON-LD. RDF/JSON was much better from this point of view...

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, it's not possible to write a context that compacts,   `{"@id": "demo:Earth","@type": ["owl:NamedIndividual","demo:Orbit"], _parameters_  },....`  into an object in this format:   `{"earth": { _parameters_ } },....`

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Is there a way to compact, `"@id": "demo:Earth", "@type": ["owl:NamedIndividual","demo:Orbit"],`  
into: `"planet": "demo:Earth",.... `?

Comment: There is no something like `demo:planet` in your original JSON-LD.